# replaceAll with regex in java

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to use `replaceAll()` for the following replacements:

```
#one# -> <element name="one">
#two# -> <element name="two">
```

and so on`...`

What regular expression do I need?

Here is a naive try:

```
replaceAll("#[\w]#", "<element name=\"[?1]\"");
// my hope is that I can remember a value somehow (`[\w]`) and use it for the substitution ([?1])
// which is, written like this, a nonsense
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("#(\\w+)#", "<element name=\"$1\">");
```

- You need `\\w+` OR `[^#]+` to match more than 1 character
- You need to put them in parentheses to make it a capturing group
- You can use back-reference to this matched group by using `$1` n replacement string